# Google sheets sends email based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a script to help send an email when a certain cell reaches a threshold value.

Here is the sheet that I have built, attached to a form with some of my own formulas.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JvF3QJSFcvJk6KnJ-f8JoQBtoblovaIMfGHxFMLCTk/edit?usp=sharing

What I would like to happen is when on the "Tracking" whenever column D reaches the value 4 an email is sent to me with the name of the student in the adjacent cell in column C.  I then need the same thing to occur when the cell changes to 5, 6, 7, ... onward.

I have utilized script to trigger emails when a cell matches a string but am struggling here with this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: While a link to an external resource might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, please add a [mcve] directly into the question body (describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet structure, add some code, add some sample data, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This function runs every 30 minutes and looks for student whose column D value equals 4.  If they have never received an email before then they join the list of students whose names are sent in the email.  The students that have already been on the list are saved in Properties Service

```
function tracking() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tracking");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, getColumnHeight(4, sh, ss) - 1, 2).getValues();
  let a = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("Students"));
  const th = 4;
  let e = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[3] == th && !~a.indexOf(r[2])) {
      e.push(r[2]);
      a.push(r[2]);
    }
  });
  if (e.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail("email address", "Subject", `Student List\n${e.join('\n')}`);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("Students", JSON.stringify(a))
  }
}

function createTrackingTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "tracking").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("tracking").timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("Students", '[]')
  }
}
```

helper function:

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```

Comment: this script is throwing the following error       TypeError: sh.getColumnHeight is not a function
tracking @ Code.gs:4

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the helper function and getColumnHeight() should not have been used with sh.  So recopy the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

## Alternate Method

You can also try this script where you can manually add the function `filterData` to any [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

This is the overview how will this script work:

1. Get the latest submission *(last row with data)* on the **Form Responses 1** sheet.
2. Get the current students and their current total counts *(C:D range)* on **Tracking** sheet.
3. On the latest student submission, check each of them on the **Tracking** sheet if any one of them has more than 4 counts on column **D**.
4. If current student submissions do not have more than 4 counts, no email will be sent, otherwise, an email will be sent containing the list of the students names.

To manually add the **filterData** function to an installable trigger, you may follow [the official guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). In my case, I tested using an **onEdit** trigger as seen below, but you can also add it to a *time-based trigger* to run the script at a specific time per day for example:

> [image]

### Script

```
function filterData(e) {
  /** Get the most recent submission on the Form Responses 1 sheet*/
  var currentStudentRecords = e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getDataRange().getValues().slice(-1).pop().filter(z => z);

  /** Gather current data from Tracking sheet get latest count of every students.
  Structure of the columnDTracking array is [sheet_row, student_name, student_count] 
  */
  var columnDTracking = e.source.getSheetByName('Tracking').getRange('C:D').getValues().map((x, index) => { return x[1] != '' ? [(index + 1), x[0], x[1]] : null }).filter(x => x);

  /** Filter the latest student record submission from sheet "Form Responses 1" who has more than 4 records on column D
   * from the Tracking sheet
   */
  var res = currentStudentRecords.map(check => {
    return columnDTracking.filter(find => { return find[1].toLowerCase() == check.toLowerCase() && find[2] >= 4 })
  }).map(JSON.stringify).filter((e, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(e)).map(JSON.parse);

  /** Send email to the student(s) who has more than 4 counts*/
  sendEmail(res)
}

/** Send email function */
function sendEmail(studentData) {
  var list = studentData.map(x => { return x.join(',').split(',')[1] == undefined ? null : '\n' + x.join(',').split(',')[1] }).filter(z => z);
  list.length == 0 ? console.log('no student with more than 4 counts') :
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "YOUR_EMAIL@YOUR_DOMAIN",
    subject: "TESTING EMAIL",
    body: "These/This student(s) has more than 4 instances: " + list
  });
}
```

### Demonstration

> Latest submission sample:

[image]

> Current count on **Tracking** sheet

[image]

> Sample Email Sent

[image]

> Sample logs if no student contains 4 counts on the latest submission and no *email* will be sent

[image]

### Reference

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)